# Paypal controlling the user experience for subscriptions + payments

Tags: paypal

Currently I use buttons (subscription + one time payments). This is a free option and has been working great.

I am looking to take control of the checkout experience for both subscriptions and payments. Is [Paypal Payments Pro](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro) the right product I am looking for?

I basically want a user to NOT know I am using paypal for processing. I would have my own payment form and my own way of managing subscriptions/updating cards.

Is this possible with PayPal Pro?

I also see  [Website Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/) which seems to add more confusion but seems to be an older product.

If someone could point me to the right product and developer docs I need to use to get started that would be great. I am very familiar with IPN so I am hoping there are good docs for this (If possible).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there are two versions of Payments Pro. You may do recurring payments with either option and it is an add on service with both versions of Pro. Pro is for direct credit card processing and keeping it on your site. Which version you want will mostly depend only on if you plan to custom code (either yourself or with a developer) or if you plan to use a shopping cart or form. Not all shopping carts work with the newer version of Pro and recurring payments. If you do plan to use a cart or form and want to check which version of Pro you should get, just give PayPal a call for assistance.

Comment: I would be doing all the development. Which one is newer and recommend to use?

Comment: The newer one is the PayPal Payments Pro Payflow edition and that would be the one that is recommended and that you would automatically receive if you apply online for Pro. Here are links to a couple of guides to look at as well: https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf and https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the information. Are there any HTML documents or just PDF's?

Comment: You're welcome. You will find quite a bit of information on it on developer.paypal.com as well searching Payflow Pro and recurring payments.